# creating react native library (create-react-native-library) with specific react-native version in its Example folder

Tags: javascript, react-native, npm

I want to create react native library . but its testing folder (example folder) contains latest react native version . But I want 0.72.6 react native version in example folder. is there any command for this??

original command : npx create-react-native-library@latest react-native-awesome-module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> npx create-react-native-library@latest brand-one-configuration
> --reactNativeVersion 0.72.6

this works